# Unable to reduce the sum of inner array after map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use the JS reduce method to add up the sum of an array, I have mapped through the developments array (as seen in the image below) and I now want to add up the value of all of the home's array. I feel like I am missing a very easy trick and can't seem to find the correct solution online. Please can someone advise me where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Find my current code below:

```js
const homesNumber = introContext.state.developments.map(development => {
    development.homes.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  });
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot `return`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing a return statement.

```js
const homesNumber = introContext.state.developments.map(development => {
    return development.homes.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  });
```

Comment: This really doesn't deserve a full answer. The nature of the problem makes this question off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree, but was just trying to help someone out :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to sum up the reduce value, you can do it, using nested reduce calls. You should also return the result of reduce using explicit `return`, or by removing the curly brackets:

```
const homesNumber = introContext.state.developments.reduce((d, a) =>
  d + a.homes.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
);
```

I would use `Array.flatMap()` to get an array of `home` values, and then sum them up:

```
const homesNumber = introContext.state.developments.
  .flatMap(o => o.homes)
  .reduce((s, n) => s + n)
```

Comment: I don't think it would be unreasonable to point out that you removed the `{ ... }` around the body of the outer arrow function, since that might not be immediately obvious to someone with mark's level of experience.

Comment: Good idea. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're just missing the `return` keyword:

```js
let developments = [
    {homes: [1,3,5]},
    {homes: [2,4,6]}
]

const homesNumber = developments.map(development => {
    return development.homes.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
})

console.log(homesNumber)
```